# Table for Custom Fields

Tags: custom-fields, mysql

I'm using Joomla and CiviCRM 4.7 and I want to add custom fields to the Participant List that's available as menu item on Joomla. I've searched all of the tables but I don't know where to find the data in the civicrm database.

I have a custom group called Conference_Selections and one of the options is for participants to choose a workshop and a study group. I want to add those fields to the participant list report so my committee can access it on the front end without having to access the report from the back end.

Is this possible? If so, where is this data stored?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to add some custom fields to the "Event Participant List" report, as displayed in this screenshot:
[image]

If so, you just need to mark those particular custom fields as "Searchable":

- Go to **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Custom Fields**
- Click **View and Edit Custom Fields** in the row labeled *Conference_Selections*.
- Next to each field that should display on the report, click **Edit Field**.
- Tick the checkbox labeled **Is this field searchable?**.

Comment: Hi Jon G, Thanks for responding. All of my custom fields are searchable.

Comment: @TeeStrong Can you update your question with a screenshot of the page we're supposed to be looking at to make sure we're understanding the question correctly?